# Google Maps API v3 - Custom Marker not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I've been searching all over and everything I try just does not work. All I'm trying to do is replace the default marker with a custom icon, but it will not show up. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.041936,-88.044523);
var mapOptions = {
    center:myLatlng,
    zoom:15,
    disableDefaultUI:true,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("milwaukeeMap"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
    marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.setIcon('/images/map-marker.png');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I know the image is in the correct location; I can find it in my browser if I type the path. I've checked and double-checked, but is there a problem with my code? Sorry, I can't provide a live example.

Comment: There is no problem with the posted code (assuming that as you indicated the marker URL is correct [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Mzr/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.041936,-88.044523);
var mapOptions = {
        center:myLatlng,
        zoom:15,
        disableDefaultUI:true,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("milwaukeeMap"), mapOptions);

var markerImage = 'images/map-marker.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: markerImage
        });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Try this, i changed how to create the marker.

I changed the image url to test it, it seams its working:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.041936,-88.044523);
var mapOptions = {
        center:myLatlng,
        zoom:15,
        disableDefaultUI:true,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("milwaukeeMap"), mapOptions);

var markerImage = 'http://www.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/bar_coktail.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: markerImage
        });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="milwaukeeMap" style="height:400px;width:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/NGja4/160/

Comment: Thanks for your input; not sure what the deal was with my image but I just moved the location and it's working now.

Comment: Where did you move it to? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small test file, and there does not seem to be anything wrong with your javascript code. I see my own marker perfectly. So it seems there is something wrong in the rest of your HTML file. Does the PNG file exists? Is it really a PNG? Maybe try a different image to be sure.

Ron.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in some cases, externally hosted icons need an extra parameter e.g.

```
images/map-marker.png?raw=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Firefox 57.0.4 for Ubuntu then I switch over to Chromium Version 63.0.3239.84 and it worked.  That is with the

```
?raw=true
```

On and off.